# Quickbooks oauth for django

Tags: django, oauth, quickbooks

I'm looking for a quick books oauth implementation in my app, i was wondering if there are any third party libraries which i can make use of instead of implementing on my own. I don't see a sample sdk for django in their website.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [django-quickbooks](https://github.com/hiidef/django-quickbooks)?

Comment: i did, i do not understand this part in it,  You'll need to set up you Keyczar keychain now:

mkdir /path/to/keys
keyczart create --location=/path/to/keys --purpose=crypt --name="A name"
keyczart addkey --location=/path/to/keys --status=primary